# What Permission Level A Provider Hosted App Needs To Have To Access SharePoint Group Users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app

I need to access SharePoint User Group in the provider hosted app, but not sure what minimum permissions will be required to achieve it.

Comment: However, my problem wasn't just the permission. I needed to configure the Azure website with the client id and client secret. http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html

Answer (score 0):

The follow App permission will do

```
   <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false">
       <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="Read" />
   </AppPermissionRequests>
```